# For each instruction to apply custom styles

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help with the following code:

1. Purpose: Apply the custom styles which names are listed in column C, in column E to show how they look like.
2. Range `C14:C46` contains a list of the styles that are set up in the workbook.
3. Range `E14:E46` should contain the example of the style, i.e. how the corresponding style looks like.
4. Code that I have developed is: `Range("E14").Style = Range("C14").Value`
5. Consequently, I believe that `For Each` instruction can replicate this code for the range `E14:E46`, but I'm not used to work with it.

**Sample:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 For i = 14 To 46
      Range("E" & i).Style = Range("C" & i).Value
 Next i
```